# Is there any way to use session multiplexing (Control Master) from windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, multiplexing

On our Repository server adding a ControlMaster to the ssd/config  file (creates socket?) resulted in a 50x transfer speed increase from roughly 2.5 seconds averaged to 0.05 seconds average. The transfer speed is between the repository system and our web servers. Now I would like to apply the same performance gain to the windows -> repository connection. We currently use Tortoise to connect via SSH, and I read on wikipedia that Putty does not natively support session multiplexing. I am aware there are other SSH tools with the feature that are also made for windows, but I was wondering if using these if I would run into issues with compatibility with Mercurial using the SSH connection as right now I believe it uses Plink to handle the SSH tunneling.

**I am looking for any options for enabling session multiplexing on windows that are compatible with Mercurial.**

Answer (score 10):

I use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for this.  The setting you're looking for is called "Share SSH connection if possible" under the "Connection->SSH" section.
From other answers, it seems to be available from PuTTY 0.64 onward.

Answer (score 2):

The pre-release of PuTTY 0.64 now has connection sharing support. Have not yet tried it myself.
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh2-generality.html

Answer (score 1):

copssh claims to allow session multiplexing but it doesn't seem like it actually does. Maybe it means that it allows multiplexing on the client side.

You could also try running Linux virtualized through andLinux and writing directly to the file system through there.